# Sonarlint not showing SonarQube java squid issues (records)

Tags: java, eclipse, sonarqube, sonarlint

Regarding issues reported by SonarLint On-The-Fly for one java file, I see a small subset of issues for the java file. As compared to the SQUID issues shown on SonarQube server for the same file.

I am using SonarQube server version 6.3, SonarLint 3.1.0.and Eclipse Neon.3. Sonarlint is connected to the server successfully and the eclipse project is linked to the project on SonarQube server. The project has component projects and this particular file is in an eclipse component project.

This squid:S1258 does not show in Sonarlint although present in the file; however this squid:S2293 shows on both Sonarlint and SonarQube.

Please advise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Sonarlint plugin apparently does not utilize the project references to other projects in eclipse. Our applications are represented in multiple eclipse projects. The solution that seems to work is simply to associate each eclipse project to the same SonarQube server project.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, in my case these are the versions in use:

- Eclipse Mars.2 (4.5.2)
- SonarLint for Eclipse 3.2.0.xxxx
- SonarQube Server 6.1
- Linux RedHat 64 bit OS

Make sure your Eclipse project is bound to the remote SonaQube server project: sometimes the binding is lost or simply the auto bind feature fails with no warning.

`Right click your Eclipse project -> SonarLint -> Bind to a SonarQube project`

On the window that pops up verify the SonarQube server is selected, click on

```
Auto bind selected projects
```

check that remote bound project is correct and then click `Finish`.

You can repeat the procedure to verify the binding is still there.
You can apply the procedure to multiple projects at once, just select them before right-clicking.